# How can replace old fragment with new fragment by another fragment's gridview clicking

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I have a Main Activity.inside that main activity i have fragment with gridview and i want change my fragment by gridview clicking.

any help...

this is my mainActivity class

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Fragment_name_list.Communicator      {
      Fragment_name_list f1;
      Fragment_tests f2;
      FragmentManager manager;

      Fragment_addStudentDetails f3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    manager=getFragmentManager();
    f1 = (Fragment_name_list) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
    f1.setCommunicator(this);
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,result);

}

@Override
public void respond(int index) {
    f2 = (Fragment_tests) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    f3 = (Fragment_addStudentDetails) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment3);
    switch (index){
        case 1:
            ///Intent i = new Intent(this,Group_AddStudent_details.class);
            ///i.putExtra("index", index);
            //startActivity(i);
            f2.changeData(index);
            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        case 3:

            break;
        case 4:
            break;
    }

}
```

}

this is my Fragment test class

```
       public class Fragment_tests extends Fragment {
TextView text;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test,container,false);
    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewp);
    return view;
}

public void changeData(int index){
    String[] result= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.result);
    text.setText(result[index]);
}
```

}

this is my Fragmnet  add student class

```
     public class Fragment_addStudentDetails extends Fragment {
TextView text;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_student_details,container,false);
    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewp);
    return view;
}
```

}

i want to replace  my fragmnet_test with fragmnet_add_student_details.
plzz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't put your Fragments in the layout xml for your main Activity. I can't see if you are doing this for sure from your code, but I suspect that's what you're doing because of the fields you are keeping to refer to the two Fragments you are working with.

What you want to do is have a ViewGroup of some sort (FrameLayout will work) that you put your Fragment into programmatically. Use `replace` on a FragmentTransaction to swap out the existing Fragment for another.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction() //
  .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new BlahFragment()) //
  .commit();
```

Also, don't use mutating methods on Fragments. If the data changes, just swap out the Fragment with the aforementioned code snippet, and get yourself a new Fragment via the documented pattern:

```
BlahFragment.newInstance(String[] data);
```

I pulled this example from the docs:

```
public static class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * Create a new instance of DetailsFragment, initialized to
     * show the text at 'index'.
     */
    public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
        DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

        // Supply index input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }
}
```